# Identifying Inner exception's Type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using EF 6, and I have a `unique index` on one property. If I try to insert a duplicate row for that column, I'll get a `DbUpdateException` exception. This exception has an inner exception that has the Error Message.

How can I directly catch that exception? String comparison doesn't look like a good option.

Comment: You can check at runtime for if `InnerExceptions != null`.

Comment: You can't directly catch it. You could however do something like `try { try { /* code */ } catch(DbUpdateException e) { throw e.InnerException; } } catch(WhateverInnerExceptionType ex) { /* whatever you want to do with the inner */ } }` . This seems redundant and *I* wouldn't do it, but it answers your question :-)

Comment: Then, how can I be sure the inner exception is the `duplicate` one? String comparison is really a bad option.

Comment: I don't understand the "string comparison" part... `InnerException` will have a type. You can do `if(e.InnerException is TheTypeOfExceptionImLookingFor) {}` in your `catch`

Comment: How can I know its type from debugger? which field :D

Comment: `InnerException` is the property to look for. It's not a string, it's an object of type `Exception` (or some descendant of it).

Comment: How can I know the type of inner exception? :) Is there any reference for that, or what field contains the type?

Comment: The `InnerException` property is an object (with a type). You can use `is` or `GetType()` or cast with `as` and check for null, or whatever other method to find the type. Same as with any other object. It's nothing special.

Comment: Well, it's from very general type of `SqlException`!

Comment: In the specific case of `SqlException`, it has a `Number` property which shows the sql thrown error code (and also an `Errors` property if there's more than one). You can check it and throw your own more specific exceptions if you need to (check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx))